# Next.js: How to dynamically import external client-side only React components into Server-Side-Rendering apps developed?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, server-side-rendering, next.js

I know this question has been asked multiple times before but none of the solution seems to work.

I'm trying to use the library 'react-chat-popup' which only renders on client side in a SSR app.(built using next.js framework) The normal way to use this library is to call `import {Chat} from 'react-chat-popup'` and then render it directly as `<Chat/>`.

The solution I have found for SSR apps is to check if `typedef of window !=== 'undefined'` in the `componentDidMount` method before dynamically importing the library as importing the library normally alone would already cause the `window is not defined` error. So I found the link https://github.com/zeit/next.js/issues/2940 which suggested the following:

```
Chat = dynamic(import('react-chat-popup').then(m => {
  const {Foo} = m;
  Foo.__webpackChunkName = m.__webpackChunkName;
  return Foo;
}));
```

However, my foo object becomes null when I do this. When I print out the m object in the callback, i get `{"__webpackChunkName":"react_chat_popup_6445a148970fe64a2d707d15c41abb03"}` How do I properly import the library and start using the `<Chat/>` element in this case?

Comment: Do you have the answer for this, because i can't find anything for the same problem.

Answer (score 14):

Next js now has its own way of doing dynamic imports with no SSR.

```
import dynamic from 'next/dynamic'

const DynamicComponentWithNoSSR = dynamic(
  () => import('../components/hello3'),
  { ssr: false }
)
```

Here is the link of their docs: [next js](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/dynamic-import#with-no-ssr)

Comment: Thank you! I always used `next/dynamic` for lazy loading. Didn't know about this use case

Comment: This only works for me for relative dependencies. However, the question asks about a component from a 3rd party library.

Answer (score 10):

I've managed to resolve this by first declaring a variable at the top:

```
let Chat = ''
```

then doing the import this way in componentDidMount:

```
async componentDidMount(){
        let result = await import('react-chat-popup')
        Chat = result.Chat
        this.setState({
            appIsMounted: true
        })
    }
```

and finally render it like this:

```
<NoSSR>
   {this.state.appIsMounted? <Chat/> : null}
</NoSSR>
```

Comment: It feels like the react-chat-popup is working horribly wrong with SSR if it requires such a hack to work, but good job for finding the solution!

Comment: Check my answer for a native way to solve this.

Comment: I had to convert the Home function into a class that extends React.Component to make this work. Thanks for this!

Comment: @AdrianGonzalez your solution doesn't solve this natively for any external dependencies, only for relative dependencies.  [Next.js even provides an alternative when dynamically importing non-components](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/dynamic-import#with-external-libraries), though there's no sample for external library components.

Answer (score -1):

> You may not always want to include a module on server-side. For
> example, when the module includes a library that only works in the
> browser.

Import the library normally in child component and import that component dynamically on parent component.

https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/dynamic-import#with-no-ssr

This approach worked for me.